# Excel Drop Down List value used in if statement to calculate totals Dynamically (on the fly)

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, excel-formula, addition

Hi I am creating a simple Entrepreneurship Aptitude for characteristics you should have and also questions, each with true and false or small answers. The questions are written in a drop down list and the answers (yes, no, maybe, etc) are also in a drop down list.

What I would like to know is how do you use an if statement that would be like:

```
=if( DropDownItemTwo at B3 == 'yes' at C3) { add 1 to the total }
```

I attached a picture so you can see my drop down list and page structure.
Beside Question on the right under 'Results' it should add to the total in the blank spot beside it ( hopefully dynamically so the user sees it updating ). This would also happen beside the characteristics title under 'Results'.

Thank you for taking time for viewing my question and possibly answering it, I look forward to knowing how to do this if it is even possible.

[image]

Comment: Is this a list drop down or VBA combo box you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can do.

1. Use `MATCH()` on your source list to output an index value to a
   cell.
2. Based on this index value and the users input (yes/no
   etc.) a decision is made.

Take a look at the attached image to get you in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: I read about  MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]). I am slightly confused how I would use that with a drop down list. Would it be like Match (C3, 3) not fairly sure about match type.

Comment: Also being new I was wondering how the strength of my question was, and if theres any way to make it better? Thanks

Comment: Question strength was fine - you formatted your text and provided a picture which is nice! Here, I'll update my picture to give you a bit of a better feel about MATCH. Essentially what it's doing is giving you an integer to describe the selection the user has made. Then, based on that integer and his yes/no, you can determine applicable outcomes.

Comment: Let me know if that helps at all!

Comment: Ok so j3 is the item or question. H3 is the answer chosen. What is h8 used for? And thank you for your feedback on my question.

Comment: H3:H8 is the range of your 'source' data.

Comment: Doesn't quite help the two lists are of different values :/

Comment: Sorry, clarify that.. I'd like to help you out here :)